# How i share any content with only one Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

How do i share any kind of content with an intent. i know to share text is `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` and for images `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`. But i want to share any content.

Comment: You have to know in advance what you are sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `putExtra` on the Intent multiple times:

```
Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imgUri);  
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
```

Comment: check this for more data http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)